# Is it possible to increase the maximum tethering sequence count in Darktable?

Tags: tethering, darktable

I'm using Darktable 1.4.2 on Ubuntu to take a sequence of photographs, but it seems the maximum count I can set is 500. Is there a way to change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit of 500 is hard-coded into the source:

```
lib->gui.sb2 = gtk_spin_button_new_with_range(1, 500, 1);
```

In file [src/libs/camera.c Line 443](https://github.com/darktable-org/darktable/blob/release-1.7.0/src/libs/camera.c#L443).

The commit message doesn't provide any reasoning for limiting it to 500.  As a user there's nothing you can do directly, but you could send the development team a note that you'd like to be able to sequence more than 500 shots and see if they can provide a better method for making that selection in a future release.  The best way to do so is probably to sign up for the Darktable mailing list and then submit your request there: https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/darktable-users

Comment: Well, you could also change the value and recompile. I think that's within the range of advanced users, at least.

Comment: @mattdm Good point. Yes, recompiling is an option. I figured I was being too technical already, but then Darktable is mainly a Linux application so the likelihood of its users being more technically inclined is probably a lot higher than the average user here.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I am up for learning how to recompile if I can't find another alternative solution.